# Update Apache using MacPorts on OS X Lion Server (10.7.4)

Tags: macos, osx-lion, macports, apache-http-server

I would like to update the existing Apache software to version 2.2.22 (currently running version 2.2.21).  I would like to use Macports but I am open to suggestions.  Whenever I try to install it, MacPorts defaults to the /opt/local directory so it installs a second instance of Apache without updating the currently installed version.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do this with MacPorts, because it's specifically designed to use /opt/local.

Comment: @Randolph West OK, but is there a way to shut down the old version and run off the new version that is installed in the /opt/local directory?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment asking whether you could disable the existing installation, I don't see why this shouldn't work:

`System Preferences` > `Sharing` > `Services` > uncheck `Personal Web Sharing`.

Then you could manage Apache from the MacPorts version. It wouldn't be through the UI though, but as long as you start the service, it should work just fine.